# operate and stay on the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC3 application in which I print some files. Here's the code part I do the printing:

```
public ActionResult Barcode(string DocumentID)
{
    barkod = new Barcode(DocumentID);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    barkod.image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    Print(barkod);
    return Redirect("Home/Index");
}
```

This could be silly, but how can I only do the printing and do nothing else here, no redirection or anything else?

I tried `EmptyResult` and returned null, but it gave me blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems you do not want to return a view then why not call it via ajax:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Barcode")', { DocumentID : docId }, function(result) {

});
```

you can also include the controller name (e.g. `SomeController`):

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Barcode","Some")', { DocumentID : docId }, function(result) {

});
```

If the print action will not take long or if you just want to return a status whether it takes too long or not:

```
public ActionResult Barcode(string DocumentID)
{
   // do your thing here
    return Json(the_status_a_boolean_or_some_other_type);
}
```

and on your js:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Barcode","Some")', { DocumentID : docId }, function(result) {
    if (result) {
        console.log("it's a success!");
    }
    else {
        console.log("something wrong went bad");
    }
}).error(function() {
    console.log('post action cannot be completed');
});
```

Comment: I don't want to do anything on the view side. @Url.Action("Barcode","Some") return something anyway even if I call it with Ajax, am I wrong?

Comment: `Url.Action` is a UrlHelper and it returns a string. "I don't want to do anything on the view side." - so how do you intend to call your `Barcode` method through a post back? If yes, then why would you prefer it over an ajax call especially if you will no redirect and you want to stay on the same page?

Comment: i think i couldn't stated my point. i just want to do an operation and not cause any changes in the view, in which i have some dropdowns and list of items changing depending on those dropdowns. i need a function which will return nothing. can i do that?

Comment: Calling an ajax post will not cause your view to change. And you can ignore the returned value so your view will not change. Invite me to a chat here if you need further clarification.